# How can I test a new nameserver before updating the registrar records?

Tags: dns, nameservers, amazon-route53

I have configured a set of DNS records at a new DNS provider. The configuration is complex, with load-balancing, SSL, etc, there are things that could go wrong.

I want to test this configuration before changing the namespace records at registrar.

- Is there any way to locally provide my machine with the new nameserver for the domain?
- Are there any tools that might help with this?

*Please note: I don't want to just update the A records (e.g. in `/etc/hosts`) - I want to specifically check the nameserver is returning the A and CNAME records.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're on a *nix system, you should be able to use either `nslookup` or `dig`. With both of those commands you can specify what server you would like to query. Simply use your new nameserver as the server. With `dig`, the query would look something like

```
dig @<your-nameserver> <hostname-to-look-up>
```

So, if you wanted to query google's public dns server and ask it about the address www.google.com, you'd use

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
```

which, amongst other things, would tell you that www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com -- and then would give you a bunch of IP address (A records) for that name.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Could you maybe update your answer with the correct command with dig (dig @ns1.google.com www.google.com). Thanks.

Comment: @iHiD `8.8.8.8` is a valid DNS server. The answer is right.

Comment: @TCB13 Yeah. He hadn't got that there when I commented :) (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10854369/revisions)

Comment: Windows `dig`??

Comment: @Petah, simply, idk. The only Windows box I have access to right now (Win7) seems to not have it, not have it installed, or not have it in PATH:
`'dig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Petah for Windows use nslookup as in
`nslookup <hostname-to-look-up> <your-nameserver>`
You can get more verbose information by using the debug flag as in 
`nslookup -debug google.com 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

For both Windows and my remote Linux(CentOS) servers I use `nslookup` tool which works on both platforms:

```
nslookup new-sub.domain.com 8.8.8.8
// and for more details:
nslookup -debug new-sub.domain.com 8.8.8.8
```